# How to know if a checkbox is selected when using robot framework

Tags: selenium2, robotframework

I am using robot framework. How can I test if a checkbox is selected?
I want to run a keyword if a checkbox is selected like:

```
 ${checked} =   Checkbox Should Not Be Selected  xpath=.//*[@id='0,1,1,6']/td[11]/input
    Run Keyword if  '${checked}'  Click Element  xpath=.//*[@id='0,1,1,6']/td[11]/input  and wait
```

i.e. to click there if is not already clicked.

(The code of above is wrong, I know)

Answer (score 1):

Use `Run Keyword And Return Status`

It runs the given keyword with given arguments and returns the status as a Boolean value. 
This keyword returns `True` if the keyword that is executed succeeds and `False` if it fails. This is useful, for example, in combination with `Run Keyword If`. If you are interested in the error message or return value, use `Run Keyword And Ignore Error` instead.

Answer (score 0):

From: [Selenium2Library documentation](http://rtomac.github.com/robotframework-selenium2library/doc/Selenium2Library.html).

**Keyword**: Checkbox Should Be Selected

**Arguments**: locator

**Documentation**: Verifies checkbox identified by locator is selected/checked.
Key attributes for checkboxes are id and name. See introduction for details about locating elements.

Comment: Thanks for answering. As you can see I am using "Checkbox should be selected" in my code (in fact I am using the negation). This command works like an assertion and not a question. When the assertion fails the test stops. I want to ask if the checkbox is checked and not to assert that the checkbox should be checked.

Comment: As mentioned in the other answer, "trap/wrap" the assertion by calling it via `Run Keyword And Return Status` which converts the pass/fail into a True/False return flag.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
${isCheck} =    Run Keyword And Return Status    Checkbox Should Be Selected   xpath=.//*[@id='0,1,1,6']/td[11]/input
```